# Creating path between many points in Google Earth

Tags: point, google-earth, path

Is there any specific way to convert approximately 25000 points in Google Earth Pro to paths or draw paths between points automatically? Since I want to obtain their altitude data, I need it to be a path (elevation profile). I drew a grid point in another software and converted it to a KML file, but I need it to be path.

Answer (score 0):

If your point data can be visualised in a GIS system such as arcmap then there are tools that will string the points together into a polyline which you can then export to a kml. You'll want to work in wgs84. I'm sure there will be equivalent tools in qgis if you prefer to use that?

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS the tool **Points to path** do this (Example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4ecutybI0w). You need to specify the field containing the order in which the points will be connected.

You can also use the following toolbox: https://plugins.qgis.org/planet/tag/routing/